# need some help in matlab displaying

Tags: matlab

this is my code where it has a matrix where it adds each row with its col where

```
as example
sum of row 1 =4
sum of col 1= 10
```

my number will be 14
so far my code works correct where number calculates all rows with col  and gives this display

```
number =

    14    18    22    26
```

in my loop os where i went wrong it split it with a counter  to show like
number 1 has 14
number 2 has 18
number 3 has 22
number 4 has 26
it works for the first one and goes to an infinite loop  and even not displaying the rest of the numbers can you tell me how to work with this and where did i go wrong thank you
**first loop result**

```
matrix =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4

1 has 14  number 
12 has 22  number
```

**code**

```
matrix=[1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4]
number= sum(matrix)+sum(matrix');
number
len= length(number);
x=1;
y=1; 
number(1,y) ; %
while x<=len
    fprintf('%x has %d  number \n',x,number)
    x+1;
    y+1;
    number
end
```

***Desired output:***

```
matrix =

     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4

number =

    14    18    22    26

1 has 14  
2 has 18
3 has 22
4 has 26
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your code calculates rowsum+colsum for each element on the diagonal and prints it. If this is not the intended output, please describe the intended output! And please use proper code indent, this increases readability.

Comment: If the value of `x` (or `len`) never change inside the loop (hint: they don't), of course it's infinite.

Comment: i modified the code to show my desired output at the end

Comment: number is sum of each row+col

Comment: value of x is incremented x+1 in the while loop but it seems not to take effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple errors in your loop:

y is unused, you can delete it.

`numbers` prints the full array each iteration, not what you want.

`x+1` calculates `x+1` but does nothing with the result. Use `x=x+1;` instead.

When using `fprint`, you are using a the full array `number` instead of the right number `number(x)` as an input argument.

```
matrix=[1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4]
number= sum(matrix)+sum(matrix');
number
len= length(number);
x=1;
while x<=len
    fprintf('%x has %d  number \n',x,number(x))
    x=x+1;
end
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel i am just working on matlab am used more with c++ command like x++ incrementation just learning from you guys thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix=[1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4;1 2 3 4]
number= sum(matrix)+sum(matrix');
number
len= length(number);
x=1;
while x<=len
    fprintf('%x has %d  number \n',x,number(x))
    x=x+1;
end
```